# How I can get test account to deploy smart contract with truffle?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, ether, kovan

With help of https://ethdrop.dev, I can get a test account with 0.001 ETH ( kovan test network ), and, I can deploy smart contract with remix ide.

I used truffle to make a solidity project, and I am trying to deploy to test network (kovan) instead of localhost(ganache).

But, with the test account, there is error: `no enough gas to deploy`

How I can get more test eth?

Or, I must use money to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a a different testnet, like [Görli testnet](https://goerli.net/).

Kovan is based on OpenEthereum (Parity) code and is being phased out.